# Can't connect to X11 server when executing jar file from php

Tags: java, php, ubuntu, x11

I am currently working on a project which requires a java program to run on the ubuntu server. This java file should be activated by php. The problem is that when I do that using this line of code:

```
shell_exec("java -jar /opt/lampp/htdocs/java/javafile.jar PARAMETERS");
```

It doesn't work and gives the error below. The weird thing is, it does work when I do it from my ubuntu terminal (without using php) or on Windows 10 (using php).

I've already tried adding this between 'java' and '-jar':

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

but this gives the following error and therefor doesn't work:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:142) at com.HotkeyCodeInc.Main.main(Main.java:56)
```

This is because I am using the Desktop function and that needs the X11 server.

**The ERROR:**

*You can check the error yourself at: http://hotkeycode.biz.tm/java/executejava.php*

```
No protocol specified Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't 
connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY 
variable. at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method) at         
sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65) at 
sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74) at 
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at 
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at 
java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103) at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82) at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.(XToolkit.java:126) at 
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at 
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at 
java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860) at 
java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854) at 
java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported(Desktop.java:169) at 
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:143) at 
com.HotkeyCodeInc.Main.main(Main.java:56)
```

**PC Information**

> Ubuntu 17.04
>
> XAMPP (as server)
>
> Apache2
>
> PHP 7.1.8

Comment: Your application seems to need graphical interfaces. Is it possible for you to forward your X11 requests to your local desktop?

Comment: @ALI I am new to Java, can you explain how to do that?

Comment: It's not really about java. 1. Why are you using php to run the java? 2.How do you run your php?

Comment: @ALI I am using php, because I want to start that java file using a URL (with parameters for the javafile). The php runs by giving the parameters in the URL and that starts the java file with the function shell_exec() (like shown above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The weird thing is, it does work when I do it from my ubuntu terminal (without using php) or on Windows 10 (using php).
>
> I am new to Java, can you explain how to do that?

I think the most important thing is to understand the difference between the GUI in Windows and the GUI in Linux:

In Windows the GUI is part of the operating system. If some program (such as a text editor) creates a window the text editor tells Windows to open a window. If you use the mouse to click on the window Windows will tell the text editor that there was a mouse click on the window.

Linux does not have a built-in GUI. Instead there is a special program called "X server" or "X11 server" which provides the GUI: If the text editor creates a window it sends a message "create window" to the X11 server; if you press the mouse the X11 server sends a message "mouse pressed" back to the text editor.

Because Linux is a multi-user OS it distinguishes between the GUI you are using and the GUI used by Apache. Because Apache does not use a GUI the Java program (started indirectly by Apache) will fail because there is no GUI available.

> This is because I am using the Desktop function ...

In both cases (Windows and Linux) your Java program will **ONLY** be able to interact with the GUI the web server is running on.

In other words:

When your web server is running on one PC and your web browser is running on another PC the Java program will access the GUI of the PC running the web server, not the GUI of the PC running the web browser!

Are you really sure that you want to do this?

Some explaination about alirabie's comment:

> Is it possible for you to forward your X11 requests to your local desktop?

The X11 system allows you to run the "X11 server" on a computer that has display, keyboard and mouse connected while the text editor (or whatever) is running on some more powerful computer - such as a web server.

This concept is similar to web-browser based "cloud" text editors where the actual text editor is running on some web server and only the web browser is running on your local computer.

So you **could** install an X11 GUI on the computer which is running the web browser and configure Apache in a way that that GUI is "used by Apache"...

However I doubt that a person without a lot of X11 knowledge is able to do so...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this stuff is beyond my skill level and I am currently working on another way to activate it. Thanks for your help!